# How can I download shared files by REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to download files from shared folders/URLs using REST API?

I need an app which can download content from chats/channels of MS Teams.

Answer (score 0):

Files in a Teams channel are stored in the SharePoint site associated with the team so you can definitely get them using the REST API. You can get to the SharePoint site associated with the Team by selecting **Open in SharePoint** in the context menu for the Team.

[image: Team context menu]

The files for each channel are stored in associated folders in the **Documents** library.

[image: Documents library]

So the REST API request to get the files would be the SharePoint site URL plus:

`/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items?$select=*,FileLeafRef,FileDirRef&$filter=FSObjType eq 0`

The `FileLeafRef` property gives you the name of the file, the `FileDirRef` property gives you the server relative URL for the folder that contains the file, the `FSObjType eq 0` filters out folders from being included in the response.

There's lots of posts on this forum and in other content that shows how to download files using the REST API. Those resources should get you the rest of the way.

For chats, I'm pretty sure you would need to use the Microsoft Graph instead of the REST API. I haven't worked with chats using Microsoft Graph so I don't have any additional details to share.

**Update**

Another option might be the [Microsoft Teams Export APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/export-teams-content). Please note that this is a premium feature of Microsoft Graph so you may need to pay licensing or consumption costs to use it.

Comment: Rob, thank you for your reply! But, unfortunately, my task is not solved. I get this list of folders: 
FormServerTemplates;
216b78431762467eacf02ef5e62eafad;
Lists;
_cts;
_private;
Social;
images;
Documents;
List;
Style Library;
_catalogs;
IWConvertedForms;
_vti_pvt; there aren't any shared folders...